# "No job configuration with the name [] was registered" exception

Tags: java, exception, spring-batch

I am seeing this exception when trying to start a new spring batch job by quartz scheduler.
This is my job configuration:

```
@Autowired
private BagCmTrkRepository bagCmTrkRepo;

@Autowired
private BagTrkRepository bagTrkRepo;

@Setter(onMethod = @__({@Autowired, @Qualifier("reposDataSource")}))
private DataSource jobDataSource;

@Setter(onMethod = @__({@Autowired, @Qualifier("slaveEntityManagerFactory")}))
private EntityManagerFactory slaveManagerFactory;

private static final String SELECT_SQL = "SELECT b " +
        "FROM Bag b " +
        "WHERE created>= :startTime and created < :endTime " +
        "AND isDone = 1";

private final String masterStepName = "bagCMMasterStep";

@Bean("bagCMPartitioning")
public BagCMPartitionerAndJobListener bagCMPartitionerAndJobListener() {
    BagCMPartitionerAndJobListener partitioner = new BagCMPartitionerAndJobListener();
    partitioner.setBagCmTrkRepo(bagCmTrkRepo);
    partitioner.setJobDataSource(jobDataSource);
    partitioner.setMasterStepName(masterStepName);
    return partitioner;
}

@Bean("bagCMReader")
@StepScope
public JpaCursorItemReader<Bag> bagCMReader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['startTime']}") Object startTime,
                                            @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['endTime']}") Object endTime) {
    JpaCursorItemReader<Bag> cursorItemReader = new JpaCursorItemReader<>();
    Map<String, Object> namedParameters = new HashMap<>() {{
        put("startTime", (Timestamp) startTime);
        put("endTime", (Timestamp) endTime);
    }};
    cursorItemReader.setName("CursorItemReader");
    cursorItemReader.setQueryString(SELECT_SQL);
    cursorItemReader.setEntityManagerFactory(slaveManagerFactory);
    cursorItemReader.setParameterValues(namedParameters);
    return cursorItemReader;
}

@Bean("bagCMProcessor")
@StepScope
public ItemProcessor<Bag, BagTrk> bagCMItemProcessor(@Value("#{stepExecution.jobExecution.jobId}") Object jobId) {
    Long cmJobId = (Long) jobId;
    return new BagCMProcessor(cmJobId);
}


@Bean("bagCMWriter")
@StepScope
public ItemWriter<BagTrk> bagCMItemWriter() {
    return new BagCMWriter(bagTrkRepo);
}

@Bean("slaveCMStep")
public Step slaveCMStep() {
    return steps.get("bagCMSlaveStep")
            .<Bag, BagTrk>chunk(10)
            .reader(bagCMReader(null, null))
            .processor(bagCMItemProcessor(null))
            .writer(bagCMItemWriter())
            .build();
}

@Bean("masterCMStep")
public Step masterCMStep() {
    return steps.get(masterStepName)
            .partitioner(slaveCMStep().getName(), bagCMPartitionerAndJobListener())
            .step(slaveCMStep())
            .gridSize(BagCMPartitionerAndJobListener.NUMBER_OF_WINDOWS)
            .taskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor())
            .build();
}

@Bean("cmJob")
public Job job() {
    return jobs.get("cmJob")
            .listener(bagCMPartitionerAndJobListener())
            .start(masterCMStep())
            .build();
}
```

**and when starting the application, I got this:**

org.springframework.batch.core.launch.NoSuchJobException: No job configuration with the name [cmJob] was registered
at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry.getJob(MapJobRegistry.java:68)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:128)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy86.getJob(Unknown Source)
at vn.ghtk.archiving.ecom.bag.cm.job.BagCMQuartzJob.executeInternal(BagCMQuartzJob.java:29)
at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:75)
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your job is missing from the job registry.

Try adding a JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor Bean to your configuration

```
    @Bean
    public JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor(JobRegistry jobRegistry) {
        JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor postProcessor = new JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor();
        postProcessor.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
        return postProcessor;
    }
```

Comment: I added but the job runs at the first time trigger and still gets this error

Comment: When debugging, i found the MapJobRegistry has empty **map**.